# merging two plots as a one and sticking them

Tags: graphics

How can I merge two (three) plots in a way that the vertical ticks of the next plot (a figure) be hidden by the previous plot (figure)? َand the final figure be referred in the text as a one figure (not two figures or sub_figures)?

[image]

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the plots pre-exist as separate images...

Merely choose the same height for the two images, and play with the `\kern` to mask out the axis labels of the right-hand image.

EDITED to simplify the syntax, a little, with

```
\underlay{<height>}{<kern>}{<leftward-image>}{<rightward-image>}
```

and

```
\addunderlay{<height>}{<kern>}{<prior-underlay-or-addunderlay>}{<rightward-image>}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}
\newcommand\underlay[4]{%
  \stackengine{0pt}%
  {\kern#2\includegraphics[height=#1]{#4}}%
  {\includegraphics[height=#1]{#3}}%
  {O}{l}{F}{F}{L}%
}
\newcommand\addunderlay[4]{%
  \stackengine{0pt}%
  {\kern#2\includegraphics[height=#1]{#4}}%
  {#3}%
  {O}{l}{F}{F}{L}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\underlay{1.5in}{120pt}{example-image-a}{example-image-b}
\caption{This is one figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\addunderlay{1in}{160pt}{%
  \underlay{1in}{80pt}{example-image-a}{example-image-b}%
}{example-image-c}

\caption{This is one figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\addunderlay{.8in}{192pt}{%
  \addunderlay{.8in}{128pt}{%
    \underlay{.8in}{64pt}{example-image-a}{example-image-b}%
  }{example-image-c}
}{example-image}

\caption{This is one figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

ORIGINAL CODE VERSION, WITHOUT HELPER MACROS:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\stackengine{0pt}
{\kern120pt\includegraphics[height=1.5in]{example-image-b}}
{\includegraphics[height=1.5in]{example-image-a}}
{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}
\caption{This is one figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\stackengine{0pt}
{\kern160pt\includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-c}}
{\stackengine{0pt}
 {\kern80pt\includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-b}}
 {\includegraphics[height=1in]{example-image-a}}
 {O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}
\caption{This is one figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\stackengine{0pt}
 {\kern192pt\includegraphics[height=.8in]{example-image}}{\stackengine{0pt}
 {\kern128pt\includegraphics[height=.8in]{example-image-c}}
 {\stackengine{0pt}
  {\kern64pt\includegraphics[height=.8in]{example-image-b}}
  {\includegraphics[height=.8in]{example-image-a}}
  {O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
 {O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}
 {O}{l}{F}{F}{L}
\caption{This is one figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Intelligently, wonderful and amazing!!!

Comment: @Irreversible The key here is to stack the leftward image *atop* the rightward image, which would not normally occur as you build left-to-right.  Thus, I use stacks and kerns to bring it about.

Comment: unfortunately I could not generalize this method to 4 or 5 figure easily. For example I added another `example-image-a` (as the fourth figure) to different position of the code but it doesn't get me a correct figure

Comment: @Irreversible I have just added the 4-image case.  Each new image requires one additional level of nesting.  I will see if I can work it into a simpler macro.

Comment: @Irreversible I have added some helper macros to (hopefully) simplify the syntax just a little.

Comment: Before the last version of the code I could add more figures. But thank you so much for simplify........thankx a bunch......

Comment: @Irreversible I have edited the question to list my original code (without the macros), at the end of the answer.